# Displaying first element user input in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, search

> We can define the term 'value of a name' as the average position of
>   the letters in the name, calculating 'A' as 1, 'B' as 2, 'C' as 3, and
>   so on. The value of "BOB" would be (2 + 15 + 2)/ 3 = 6. According to
>   this value, the names will be arranged from the smallest towards the
>   biggest in the output. ***When two or more names have the same value,
>   the name which is in the first position in the original list (the
>   first one the user inputs) should show up first in the sorted list
>   (the output).***
>
> Input In the first line we have an integer N (1 <= N <= 100), which is
>   the number of names. In every of the N lines we have one name ([A-Z],
>   no empty spaces). Names contain 1 - 200 letters.
>
> Output Print out the sorted list (one name in a line).
>
> Test-case
>
> Input: 3 BOB AAAAAAA TOM  Output: AAAAAAA BOB TOM

I tried something, and the code seemed to work, I just had a problem with the output. I couldn't find a way to arrange the names with the same value, according to their position in the original list. Here's the other test-case I tried, but didn't figure out:

```
Input:


 10
 COSOPYILSPKNKZSTUZVMEERQDL
 RRPPNG
 PQUPOGTJETGXDQDEMGPNMJEBI
 TQJZMOLQ
 BKNGFEJZWMJNJLSTUBHCFHXWMYUPZM
 YNWEPZKNBOOXNZVWKIUS
 LV
 CJDFYDMYZVOEW
 TMHEJLIDEHT
 KGTGFIFWYTKPWTYQQPGKRRYFXN
```

> ```
> Output:
> TMHEJLIDEHT
> PQUPOGTJETGXDQDEMGPNMJEBI
> BKNGFEJZWMJNJLSTUBHCFHXWMYUPZM
> CJDFYDMYZVOEW
> RRPPNG
> COSOPYILSPKNKZSTUZVMEERQDL
> KGTGFIFWYTKPWTYQQPGKRRYFXN
> TQJZMOLQ
> YNWEPZKNBOOXNZVWKIUS
> LV
>
> My output:
>
> TMHEJLIDEHT 
> PQUPOGTJETGXDQDEMGPNMJEBI
> CJDFYDMYZVOEW // these two
> BKNGFEJZWMJNJLSTUBHCFHXWMYUPZM // should be arranged with their places switched
> RRPPNG 
> COSOPYILSPKNKZSTUZVMEERQDL 
> KGTGFIFWYTKPWTYQQPGKRRYFXN 
> TQJZMOLQ 
> YNWEPZKNBOOXNZVWKIUS 
> LV
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int N;
cin >> N;

string words[N];

int res[N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    string word;
    cin >> words[i];
    word = words[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
        sum += (int)word[j] - 64;
    }
    value = sum / word.length();
    res[i] = value;
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (res[i] < res[j]) {
            swap(res[i], res[j]);
            swap(words[i], words[j]);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << words[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: use stable_sort in the stl, alternatively use merge sort (n log n time complexity means it will perform quite fast)

Comment: Your sorting function sorts, but doesn't preserve order of equivalent elements. So use a different algorithm, such as bubble sort.

Comment: Use `std::multimap<int, string>`

Comment: `int N; cin >> N; string words[N];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a constant, not a runtime value.  Use `std::vector<std::string> words(N);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string words[N];
int res[N];
```

This here is not valid C++, you can not size a stack array using a runtime variable, although *some* compilers might support such a feature. You might use say `std::vector` instead, which behaves much like an array.

```
vector<string> words;
vector<int> res;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    words.push_back(word);
    for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
        sum += (int)word[j] - 64;
    }
    value = sum / word.length();
    res.push_back(value);
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (res[i] < res[j]) {
            swap(res[i], res[j]);
            swap(words[i], words[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The ordering is because your sorting algorithm is not stable. Stable means that items with equal values will maintain the same order relative to each other.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (res[i] < res[j]) {
            swap(res[i], res[j]);
            swap(words[i], words[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

What you have is very close to bubble sort, which is stable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N - i - 1; j++) { // i elements sorted so far
        if (res[j] > res[j + 1]) {
            swap(res[j], res[j + 1]);
            swap(words[j], words[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

C++ also provides a stable sort in `<algorithm>`, but it can't function directly on two arrays like this unfortunately, one option is to compute the value on the fly, another could be to make a class holding both items and sort that, or another to sort the indices.

```
std::stable_sort(words.begin(), words.end(), [&](auto &a, auto &b)
{
    int suma = 0, sumb = 0; // better yet, make a "int value(const string &str)" function.
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
        suma += (int)a[j] - 64;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
        sumb += (int)b[j] - 64;
    }
    int valuea = suma / a.length();
    int valueb = sumb / b.length();
    return valuea < valueb;
});
```

A class containing both items is pretty straight forward, for indices, make a 3rd array and sort that.

```
vector<size_t> indices;
...
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    indices.push_back(words.size());
    words.push_back(word);
...
std::stable_sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&](auto a, auto b){ return res[a] < res[n]; });
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << words[indices[i]] << endl;
}
```

Comment: The issue with your `stable_sort` predicate is that it is calculating the average each and every time it's called for both words.  The average will not change, so why calculate it repeatedly?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why I said it's unfortunate you can't just use it "directly" in any way I can think of, the `indices` array for example avoids that repeat, as would a `struct { value, string }`, maybe a map as well.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be order the result array during construction.

When you add the words in the result array, use the result obtained to add the word in the right place. In this way you can check if exist already the same value and add the new word after the previous with the same value.

Comment: How would that work? Would it be okay for you to edit my code?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the next word use insertion sort ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)) which is stable

1. read word
2. calculate value
3. insert in a right place in the array
4. go to 1 until `i < N` otherwise print out

Doesn't require additional sorting procedure.

Answer (score 1):

in python:

```
def sort_list(list1, list2): 

    zipped_pairs = zip(list2, list1) 

    z = [x for _, x in sorted(zipped_pairs)] 

    return z

times = int(input())

entries = []
ordered = []

for x in range(times):
    entries.append(input())

for x in entries:
    chars = []
    for y in x:
        chars.append(ord(y) - 96)
    ordered.append(sum(chars))

print(sort_list(entries,ordered))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just order them in the end (You won't need the 2nd array):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        int sumA = 0, sumB = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < words[i].size(); k++)
            sumA += words[i][k] - 'A' + 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < words[j].size(); k++)
            sumB += words[j][k] - 'A' + 1;
        if (sumA / words[i].size() > sumB / words[j].size())
            swap(words[i], words[j]);
    }
}
```

As they shown above, it's way better to use a vector to store your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [`std::multimap<int, std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), there would be no need to sort, as the key would already serve as the sorting criteria.

Here is a solution using `std::multimap`:

```
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

// Test data
std::string test = "10\n"
"COSOPYILSPKNKZSTUZVMEERQDL\n"
"RRPPNG\n"
"PQUPOGTJETGXDQDEMGPNMJEBI\n"
"TQJZMOLQ\n"
"BKNGFEJZWMJNJLSTUBHCFHXWMYUPZM\n"
"YNWEPZKNBOOXNZVWKIUS\n"
"LV\n"
"CJDFYDMYZVOEW\n"
"TMHEJLIDEHT\n"
"KGTGFIFWYTKPWTYQQPGKRRYFXN\n";

int main()
{
    std::istringstream strm(test);

    // Read in the data
    std::multimap<int, std::string> strmap;
    int N;
    strm >> N;
    std::string word;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        strm >> word;

        // get the average using std::accumulate and divide by the length of the word
        int avg = std::accumulate(word.begin(), word.end(), 0,
                    [&](int total, char val) { return total + val - 'A' + 1; }) / word.length();

        // insert this value in the map
        strmap.insert({ avg, word });

    }

    // output results 
    for (auto& w : strmap)
        std::cout << w.second << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
TMHEJLIDEHT
PQUPOGTJETGXDQDEMGPNMJEBI
BKNGFEJZWMJNJLSTUBHCFHXWMYUPZM
CJDFYDMYZVOEW
RRPPNG
COSOPYILSPKNKZSTUZVMEERQDL
KGTGFIFWYTKPWTYQQPGKRRYFXN
TQJZMOLQ
YNWEPZKNBOOXNZVWKIUS
LV
```

The [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is used to add up the values to get the average.